# Regex match 4 bytes unicode characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex which can find all 4 byte unicode characters in a string. I would like to make the following compatible with all popular browsers.

The following code works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but Safari throws "Invalid regular expression: range out of order in character class"

```
var match = 'aaaaaa'.match(/[\u{10000}-\u{10FFFF}]/gu);
```

So my questions is how should I change the regexp to be able to match all 4 byte unicode characters in a string and without the use of the unicode feature of regex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Safari does not support ES6 regular expression syntax. All you can do is [transpile](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/regexpu) the regex to conform with the ES5 regex syntax:

```js
console.log('aaaaaa'.match(/(?:[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF])/g));
```